# MYSQL Select using WHERE, AND, OR

Tags: mysql, select, operators, where-clause

I am trying to get a selection of data out of my database but am having trouble, I'm sure its something simple that I am not seeing but I cant figure it out.

A table, jobs, has 5 fields: job_id, job_status, job_schedulestatus, job_schedulestatus2, job_schedulestatus3. The id is a auto incremented number, the status can have two values Active or Invoiced and the schedule status can each hold a large number of values that are selected from a drop down but in this case I just want to focus on values called FOC, Cancelled and Sample.

What I am trying to do is select all values that are set to active and don't have FOC, Cancelled or Sample set in the schedule status 1-3

Here is my select statement:

```
SELECT job_id, job_status, job_schedulestatus, job_schedulestatus2, job_schedulestatus3
FROM jobs WHERE job_status='Active' 
AND ( job_schedulestatus!='FOC' OR job_schedulestatus!='Cancelled' OR job_schedulestatus!='Sample' )
OR ( job_schedulestatus2!='FOC' OR job_schedulestatus2!='Cancelled' OR job_schedulestatus2!='Sample' )
OR ( job_schedulestatus3!='FOC' OR job_schedulestatus3!='Cancelled' OR job_schedulestatus3!='Sample' )
ORDER BY job_id DESC;
```

This still shows all fields that have FOC, Cancelled or Sample. Now if I remove the `!=` and replace with just `=` it will only show those with FOC, Cancelled or Sample which suggests to me that there is an issue using the `!=`. I tried replcaing with `<>` but still doesn't work.

If I just test it with one check on the schedule status it works as below:

```
SELECT job_id, job_status, job_schedulestatus, job_schedulestatus2, job_schedulestatus3
FROM jobs WHERE job_status='Active' AND job_schedulestatus!='Cancelled
ORDER BY job_id DESC;
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you mix `AND` and `OR` in SQL, do also remember to use parentheses to define the evaluation order. This is due to the fact that they are parsed at different order.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT job_id, job_status, job_schedulestatus, job_schedulestatus2, job_schedulestatus3
FROM jobs WHERE job_status='Active' 
AND  (job_schedulestatus NOT IN ('FOC','Cancelled','Sample') 
OR job_schedulestatus2 NOT IN ('FOC','Cancelled','Sample')
OR job_schedulestatus3 NOT IN ('FOC','Cancelled','Sample'))
ORDER BY job_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems easier to process:

```
SELECT job_id
     , job_status
     , job_schedulestatus
     , job_schedulestatus2
     , job_schedulestatus3
  FROM jobs 
 WHERE job_status = 'Active' 
   AND 
     ( job_schedulestatus  NOT IN ('FOC','Cancelled','Sample') 
    OR job_schedulestatus2 NOT IN ('FOC','Cancelled','Sample') 
    OR job_schedulestatus3 NOT IN ('FOC','Cancelled','Sample')
     )
 ORDER 
    BY job_id DESC;
```

Note that generally, where you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2) you can be confident that your schema design is sub-optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this doesn't seem to work either, it will not show a value if job_schedulestatus, job_schedulestatus2 and job_schedulestatus3 are all set with either FOC, Cancelled, Sample but if only 1 or 2 of them have one of these values

Comment: In which case, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: of course, here is a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a980d/1, appears to work here, maybe there is something before my code thats causing issues

Comment: It works on the sqlfiddle but not on my working code. I assumed the problem was with that section but must be something else

Comment: OK, well obviously, we can only address the question asked, and the information provided in support of that.

Comment: Sorry, I have added more data to my fiddle and it does appear to still show some values that have FOC etc http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b21ae6/1

Comment: What should it show? 3 & 2 only? In which case you would appear to be confusing OR and AND.

Comment: Yes 2 and 3 only

Comment: I see, so changing the two OR to AND chows 2 and 3.

Comment: And that works on my Live code, thank you for all your help